# Trying to establish a random variable for a specific scenario but the outcome seems to ignore the "if" statement

Tags: javascript, variables, key

I am trying to get a random climate condition for a particular map, but I don't want certain climate conditions to occur for some maps (eg, if the area is tropical, I don't want snow and ice). Here's an example of the conditions I am setting:

```
let climate;
  if (mapNumber === "One" || "Three" || "Four") { 
    climate = ["dry", "light rain", "medium rain", "heavy rain", "light snow", "medium snow", "heavy snow", "light ice", "very icy", "severe ice"];
    climateCondition = Math.floor(Math.random() * climate.length);
    keyClim = climate[climateCondition];
  } else if (mapNumber === "Two" || "Five") { 
    climate = ["dry", "light rain", "medium rain", "heavy rain"];
    climateCondition = Math.floor(Math.random() * climate.length);
    keyClim = climate[climateCondition];
  } else climate = false; 
    console.log("Climate conditions", climateCondition, climate[climateCondition]);
```

When I first called this, I just made separate conditions for each map, but the code was way too long and I am trying to refactor into a small amount of code (about 5 times smaller).

So what I would like to happen, I have a global variable "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", or "Five" (at the moment, but would like to be able to add more if need be). So, in this case maps "One", "Three" and "Four" can develop snow and ice (though I would actually prefer map "Four" to only have light snow and light ice, but I can work that out when I sort this far). Then that variable can be used later as "climate" + mapNumber.

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work and currently I am just hitting a brick wall. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do something like:

```
(mapNumber === "One" || "Three" || "Four")
```

Because that means: `mapNumber === "One"` or if `"One"` is not defined (which is obviously not the case here since `"One"` is a string so it's defined) `mapNumber === "Three"` and if `"Three"` is not defined (which is not the case for the same reason) `mapNumber === "Four"`. So it only test the first condition: `mapNumber === "One"`.

You have to do:

```
(mapNumber === "One" || mapNumber === "Three" || mapNumber === "Four")
```

or

```
["One", "Three", "Four"].includes(mapNumber)
```

Comment: If that solves your issue can you valid the answer so the question can be closed?